# Make multiline inline button name aiogram python

Tags: python, bots, telegram, inline, aiogram

I try to make telegram bot using aiogram module python. I have some problems. Is it possible to make multiline name inline button? I try to write "Some text...\n...some text",but it doesn't work. Is it possible to change the size of inline button?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**No. You cannot change its shape.**

[InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) has only one field.

If you want to write larger text, use [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup).

```py
def keyboard():
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=False, row_width=2)
    user = KeyboardButton(' User')
    admin = KeyboardButton('‍ Admin')
    markup.add(user, admin)
    return markup
```

[image: keyboards]

With `resize_keyboard=False` you can make the buttons bigger